# Select newly added Row - DataGridView and BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce, bindingsource

I'm adding a new Row to a BindingSource that is Bound to a DataGridView

```
source.AddNew();
```

After this, use BindingSource to get the newly added row is return the next row in the DataGridView when its sorted.

```
ROW "A"
ROW "B" <- myBindingSource.AddNew();
ROW "C"
```

myBindingSource.Current gives ROW "C". (it became the selected row in the DataGridView)

I need this because I want to update just the newly added row

```
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)myBindingSource.Current;
            myTableAdapter.Update(drv.Row);
```

and not the entire table.

```
            myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.myTable);
```

and also, I would like to have this newly added line selected in the DataGridView after insertion.

is it possible in some way?

Comment: same sort of question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191339/how-to-set-selected-row-of-datagridview-to-newly-added-row-when-the-grid-is-bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know id its the best solution but for instance looks better than iterate.

```
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)source.AddNew();
        grupoTableAdapter.Update(drv.Row);
        grupoBindingSource.Position = grupoBindingSource.Find("ID", drv.Row.ItemArray[0]);
```

Comment: it makes the DataGridView that is bound to select the new added row accordingly even if any column is sorted out.

Answer (score 8):

Use the events from the DataGridView like this for this task:

```
private void RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

That marks the newly added row as the selected.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? I would say `yes`.

Here's an aricle related to it:
[DataGridView and BindingSource](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.481532.1) (on Joel's Forum)

Answer (score 0):

You've already identified one way to accomplish this.  Another way to accomplish it is to ignore the UI completely:

```
foreach (DataRow r in myTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.RowState == DataRowState.Added))
{
    myTableAdapter.Update(r);
}
```

Of course, this calls `Update` on *all* added rows in the table, not the one that was just added, so if you have some crazy scenario where you have two different ways of adding new rows to the table it won't work.

Comment: Yes, but it iterates and dont make the new added line selected in the View. Could be of some help in some situation anyway. Thanks by the help.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from Oliver Friedrich's answer, the function when created using the controls's property as shown in the designer will look like:

```
private void drv_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    drv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```