# VB.NET Winforms DataGridView Select new row on Sorted DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

Alright I have a DataGridView, where the user can click on the column headers to sort.  When they add a new row while a sort is applied, the record isn't created until the moment they validate the row(which they cannot do till they exit the newRow).  How can I make the row be selected once it is sorted?

The DataGridView is databound.

The selection mode for the grid is full row.

I'm using VB.NET with SQLite database backend.

I suspect I need to use the RowsAdded event, or DataBindingComplete events.  The records in question do have a unique GUID attached but it is NOT visible in the DataGridView.

This c# question seems sort of along the lines of what I want: [Select newly added Row - DataGridView and BindingSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664537/select-newly-added-row-datagridview-and-bindingsource).  However the question is how do I make it fire the row validate (and thus the binding to DB) without leaving the row.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Store the primary key (id) of the added record into a new field(insert command returns that), and loop through the gridview rows and select the row with the primary key. :)